# ThreeJS: Is there any way to show only the edge in after cutting the geometry using CSG

Tags: three.js

I use CSG to cut a geometry using another geometry. After when I try to apply an edge to the final geometry (cut geometry), It doesn't apply properly where it has a lot of cut details that are applied to the edge. Is there any way to overcome it and apply the edge only to the geometry with the unwanted edge?
Here's the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/r9kzj45b/

```
  var scene, renderer, camera, controls;

    basicScene();

    var height = 0.2;
    var width = 5;
    var length = 5;

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xFFFFFF,
        flatShading: true
    });

    var box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, length));
    // CSG GEOMETRY
    var box_bsp = new ThreeBSP(box);

    var cutgeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 16, 8);
    // move geometry to where the cut should be
    var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    matrix.setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1));
    cutgeo.applyMatrix(matrix);

    var cutmesh = new THREE.Mesh(cutgeo);
    var cutmesh_bsp = new ThreeBSP(cutmesh);
    var subtract_bsp = box_bsp.subtract(cutmesh_bsp);

    var result = subtract_bsp.toMesh(material);
    // not sure if cVN still necessary
    result.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    scene.add(result);

    const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(result.geometry);
    const line = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff }));
    scene.add(line);



    animate();

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    function basicScene() {
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true
        });
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;

        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        // background color
        renderer.setClearColor(0x55ff55, 1);

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 1, 10000);
        camera.position.y = 10;
        camera.position.z = 10;
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        var aL = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
        scene.add(aL);

        var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        dirLight.position.set(-1, 1.75, 1);
        dirLight.position.multiplyScalar(50);
        scene.add(dirLight);

        var gridXZ = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 10);
        scene.add(gridXZ);
    }
```

[image]